# Trying to restrict my site to a specific country

Tags: php, geoip

I am trying to restrict my site to a specific country using this code that I found and I can't seem to be able to get it to work.

My problem is that its always returning true even when `$country` is different than what's in the array

I know restricting my site by GeoIP isn't fool proof but it will keep my issue down of people trying to signup from different countries as the events we host are limited to a small geographic area.

I have checked to see if my issue has to do with caching and my site isn't caching the output.

I also know that `$country` is working as I've tried `echo ($country);`

Here is the code

```
$allowed_countries = array("CA", "US");

$country = file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}/country");


if (in_array($country, $allowed_countries)) {

  header('Location: http://www.letsgetsocialclub.com/site');

} else {

echo "Sorry The Let's Get Social Club is not available in your country";

}
```

Comment: what does var_dump(  $country, $allowed_countries, in_array($country, $allowed_countries));  return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url you use for your request returns the country code with `\n` at the end, so the value your are trying to check is not inside your array.
You can use the [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function to remove all white-spaces from the beginning and end of your string to clean it:

```
$country = trim(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}/country"));
```

Answer (score 0):

To make sure there is no extra characters with the country code, replace your code with the following:

```
$allowed_countries = array("CA", "US");

$country = preg_replace('/[^A-Z]/', '', file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}/country"));


if (in_array($country, $allowed_countries)) {

  header('Location: http://www.letsgetsocialclub.com/site');

} else {

echo "Sorry The Let's Get Social Club is not available in your country";

}
```